# Role mappings of all matched users in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How to fetch all the role mappings of a single user in Elasticsearch.
I have role mapping like this:

```
"sdbsd21tdsbjvbriuu": {
        "enabled": true,
        "roles": [
            "kibana_dashboard_only_user",
            "5e3bb57222b49800016b666f"
        ],
        "rules": {
            "all": [
                {
                    "field": {
                        "realm.name": "oidc1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "field": {
                        "username": [
                            "user001@one.com",
                            "User002@two.com",
                            "USER003@three.com"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "metadata": {
            "migrated": false
        }
    }
```

For e.g. `user001@one.com` can be there across multiple role-mappings. I want to fetch all the role-mappings with `user001@one.com`. How to do that?
I have tried to search the `security-7` index. However, unable to get a single search query for this.

```
GET .security-7/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "doc_type": "role-mapping"
                    }
                }                
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The mapping of the `.security-7` index is:

```
{
    ".security-7": {
        "mappings": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "_meta": {
                "security-version": "7.6.2"
            },
            "properties": {
                "access_token": {
                    "properties": {
                        "invalidated": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        },
                        "realm": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "user_token": {
                            "properties": {
                                "authentication": {
                                    "type": "binary"
                                },
                                "expiration_time": {
                                    "type": "date",
                                    "format": "epoch_millis"
                                },
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                },
                                "metadata": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "dynamic": "false"
                                },
                                "version": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "actions": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "api_key_hash": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "index": false,
                    "doc_values": false
                },
                "api_key_invalidated": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "application": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "applications": {
                    "properties": {
                        "application": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "privileges": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "resources": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "cluster": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "creation_time": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "epoch_millis"
                },
                "creator": {
                    "properties": {
                        "metadata": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "dynamic": "false"
                        },
                        "principal": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "realm": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "doc_type": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "email": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "email"
                },
                "enabled": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "expiration_time": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "epoch_millis"
                },
                "full_name": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "global": {
                    "properties": {
                        "application": {
                            "properties": {
                                "manage": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "applications": {
                                            "type": "keyword"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "indices": {
                    "properties": {
                        "allow_restricted_indices": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        },
                        "field_security": {
                            "properties": {
                                "except": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                },
                                "grant": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "names": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "privileges": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "query": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "limited_by_role_descriptors": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "dynamic": "false"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "password": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "index": false,
                    "doc_values": false
                },
                "refresh_token": {
                    "properties": {
                        "client": {
                            "properties": {
                                "realm": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                },
                                "type": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                },
                                "user": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "invalidated": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        },
                        "refresh_time": {
                            "type": "date",
                            "format": "epoch_millis"
                        },
                        "refreshed": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        },
                        "superseding": {
                            "properties": {
                                "encrypted_tokens": {
                                    "type": "binary"
                                },
                                "encryption_iv": {
                                    "type": "binary"
                                },
                                "encryption_salt": {
                                    "type": "binary"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "token": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "role_descriptors": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "role_templates": {
                    "properties": {
                        "format": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "template": {
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "roles": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "rules": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "dynamic": "false"
                },
                "run_as": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "type": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "username": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "version": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
**To all future readers of this question, I have followed up with Elasticsearch team. As I had OIDC realm based role mapping. As of Elasticsearch 7.8, there is no solution available to my question. The best possible way is to parse the response JSON. I had gone with this approach.**

Comment: Could you share the mapping details of the index `.security-7`. Just want to make sure the `nested` aspect of the fields that you have.

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal, the mapping has been added to the question. However, I could not found any `nested` field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the get user API and for that you need to hit `_security` not `.security-7` index,

I created when x-pack is enabled like below:

URL http://{{hostname}}:{{port}}/_security/user/foo

```
{
    "username": "foo",
    "full_name": "foo bar",
    "email": "foo@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456",
    "roles": [
        "ADMIN"
    ]
}
```

And then using get user API I can get its details:

Just change the above method to GET and you will get below o/p, where you can see its role also shown.

```
{
    "foo": {
        "username": "foo",
        "roles": [
            "ADMIN"
        ],
        "full_name": "foo bar",
        "email": "foo@gmail.com",
        "metadata": {},
        "enabled": true
    }
}
```

Comment: This works only for the `superuser` role-based users. Other users, I am unable to see as I asked on the question.

Comment: @Soumendra for me it works for other users as well who are not super user, can you explain your issue in detail like how you are creating users (which API etc)

Comment: Maybe cause it is OIDC based user role mapping, that's why it is not visible to me. For the future viewer to this question, I have followed this up with Elasticsearch customer support team, they said this feature what I am looking for is not available yet.

Comment: This doesn't quite match the OP's question but for a user who has logged in via OIDC SSO, this is how to discover what roles they have been mapped to/assigned: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78160290