# Elasticsearch: how to list roles assigned to the current SSO user via role mappings

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I find out which roles I have been assigned, having authenticated to an Elasticsearch cluster via OIDC SSO?

The setup is that roles have been assigned to me in AzureAD (to which I do not have access) and then I have logged in to Elastic using oidc/AzureAD.

Having logged in, I wish to know which roles of those listed under /app/management/security/roles were actually granted to me, by Azure claims, via one of the role mappings at /app/management/security/role_mappings

I can view which *privileges* I have via Kibana dev tools `GET _security/user/_privileges` but this doesn't tell me which roles they came from. The Get User API `GET /_security/user` doesn't help as it only includes native/builtin users, not SSO users.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I figured out that you can discover this for the current user by calling the [Authenticate API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-authenticate.html) from Kibana dev tools (/app/dev_tools) e.g:

```
GET /_security/_authenticate
```

returns something like this, crucially with the `roles` list:

```
{
  "username": "seemingly_random_number",
  "roles": [
    "editor",
    "viewer",
    "superuser"
  ],
  "full_name": "my.azure.upn@company.com",
  "email": "my.azure.upn@company.com",
  "metadata": {
    "saml_...": ...
  },
  ...
}
```